# Simple function to verify if a number is integer

Tags: javascript, integer

Sometimes, there's the need to verify if a given number is an integer or a decimal. Since JavaScript doesn't distinguish between both, I've made an extremelly basic function.

```
function isInteger(num){
    var numCopy = parseFloat(num);
    return !isNaN(numCopy) && numCopy == numCopy.toFixed();
}
```

As you can see, it relies on checking if the number without decimals is the same as the parsed value. I'm not so confident about this.

Notice that this may return `true` for some scientific notation values.

Examples of results:

- `1.0`: `true` (JavaScript treats `<n>.0` as an integer)
- `1e3`: `true`
- `1.2345e2`: `false` (equivalent to 123.45)
- `1.2345e5`: `true` (equivalent to 123450)
- `1e200`: `true` (equivalent to `Infinity`)

Is there any more reliable way of checking? The results seem to be consistent with the expected results. Regular expressions are an option but they are clunky.

Comment: Have you checked out the polyfill or ES6's isInteger function? Check it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger - I think this is agreeably the best way to find out, but as always, be aware of JS rounding stuff for you.

Comment: @somethinghere That's a really great suggestion! Put it in the form of an answer and I'll upvote it for sure

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ES6, the next version of Javascript, there will be a function exactly for this purpose called `Number.isInteger()`. Currently, MDN offers the following polyfill which I assume therefore does the best Javascript can to determine whether something is an integer. There are edge cases of course, but for most everyday use it will do the trick:

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" && 
           isFinite(value) && 
           Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

I think this is the best we will do in the meanwhile, as passing string to a number function is an effective way of doing it, but calling `toString` on a number makes it go through conversion as well, resulting in potential issues.

There are already a couple of browsers that support it like Chrome and Firefox, but the big one (Safari) doesn't yet and neither does IE/Edge, so the polyfill will have to do. For more info, see MDN's writeup, it's quite insightful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Browser_compatibility

**Note: Polyfills like this are useful, but there are some concerns about amending these core features of JS. As I say in the comments, as long as you implement something that doesn't exist or replace anything, I think it's alright. *Use in moderation*.**

You can always wrap it in it's own function and call it as a global function if you prefer not to use this polyfill.

Comment: I would just add a line saying that messing with `prototypes` is a bad practice, and that this can be used as a simple named function. Other than that, +10 for you!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I have heard a lot about it being bad to mess with prototypes in this way, but nobody ever explained me _why_. I understand _rewriting_ a method from, say, `Number` is dangerous because it gives unexpected results, but adding a method seems perfectly harmless to me. Do you have got any good references on why prototype amending is bad? I'd love to read about that.

Comment: At the moment, I don't recall any article to read. But imagine that your code relies on some polyfill, that is set to the prototype. If anyone changes the prototype by, for example, doing `window.Number = window.String`, your whole code is broken. Besides, messing with prototypes may crash with other codes that rely on a specific prototype method to return a non-standard value or has a different behaviour.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of what I meant though, you don't mess with prototypes themselves, but I think appending a method is perfectly fine as long as it does not replace an already existing method. It might be best to have an ES6 check first (`if(!Number.isInteger)`), but otherwise I really think _this particular thing_ is harmless. Replacing Number with Int etc... Thats obviously bad :)

Comment: Exactly. We know it's bad, but does someone else know? Besides, I'm sure someone will nitpick on the same point as well. It takes you only 1 minute and your answer is massivelly improved.

Comment: I concur, so I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a little vague, but right away I tried to break it and was successful with this

```
function isInteger(num){
    var numCopy = parseFloat(num);
    return !isNaN(numCopy) && numCopy == numCopy.toFixed();
}
```

> ```
> isInteger(.9999999999999999999998/.9999999999999999999999);
> true
> ```

probably because of loss of precision, as [@Gallant](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/74508/gallant) noted the decimals are getting rounded to zero

Depending on what you are doing this is probably sufficiently accurate.

Comment: This is more accurately due to loss of precision from floating point values; both decimals are getting rounded to `1` before the division occurs. `isInteger(.9999999999999999999998)` would also return true because of this.

Comment: @Gallant, you are totally right.

Comment: If you have a look at the ES6 polyfill of `isInteger` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) you will see this also fails this test. Javascript simply cannot compute these properties without converting them, so they will also wind up being 1.